# Scoped Service not being shared as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

##### Context

For context, my code and problem in question is an almost identical copy of the [Blazor Server with EF Core Demo](https://github.com/dotnet/blazor-samples/tree/main/6.0/BlazorServerEFCoreSample). The primary difference is that all my UI C# is written in base classes using the code-behind pattern.

As is seen in the demo app, my code has a filters service used to help keep state between components. On my ManageUsers.razor component, I have a child component to toggle how the names in the contacts list are displayed (NameToggle.razor). If `Filters.Loading` is TRUE, then the button is disabled so as not to attempt to modify a list that's actively being built.

##### My Issue

My issue is that whenever I use `NavigationManager.NavigateTo()` to navigate between the various component pages (e.g., ViewContact, EditContact) and then back to the main component page, the state of `Filters.Loading` on the main component page and `Filter.Loading` of its child components are different.

To be clearer, I've provided code snippets of three of my components below. The ManageUsers.razor components is the parent of NameToggle.razor and UserRow.razor. The UserRow component uses the `NavigationManager` service to navigate to another routable component, which then uses that same service to navigate back to ManageUsers.razor. However, when you navigate away and back in this manner, the button rendered by NameToggle.razor is disabled. After printing the values to the screen, I can see that even though `Filters.Loading` is FALSE in the ManageUsers.razor, it is TRUE in the child components like NameToggle.razor.

##### Things I've done so far

I have spent hours comparing my code to the demo and reading through documentation. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this is happening. The service is indeed registered with a SCOPED lifetime. I've thought of some ideas as to why it might not be working, but again, after hours of comparing my code and reading the docs, I've come up short. Some of those ideas were that maybe using `null!;` on the injected properties was causing an issue. Per the documentation, I changed it to being `default!;`, but nothing changed.
I thought that maybe the cascading parameter of the UserTableWrapper.razor component might have been null, but I also tested that and it's never null.

##### Further context

Not sure if this really matters, but my solution is using clean architecture. I have my Filters interface written in my Application.dll and its implementation written in Infrastructure.dll. Additionally, I have the service registrations for the infrastructure layer in the same layer.

##### Code

**Program.cs Snippet**

```
    WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
        // Configure and add application logger as it should be for run-time.
        builder.Host.AddSerilog();
    
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddApplicationServices();
        builder.Services.AddInfrastructureServices(builder.Configuration);
        builder.Services.AddWebUIServices();
    
        WebApplication app = builder.Build();
```

**InfrastructureServices.cs**

```
    using FLA.Application.Common.Interfaces;
    using FLA.Domain.Entities.Identity;
    using FLA.Infrastructure.Common.Filtering;
    using FLA.Infrastructure.Persistence;
    using FLA.Infrastructure.Persistence.Seeding;
    
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    
    namespace FLA.Infrastructure.DependencyInjection;
    
    /// <summary> Extensions for adding and configuring services from the Infrastructure project. </summary>
    public static class InfrastructureServices
    {
        /// <summary> Adds and configures services from the infrastructure layer to the application's services container. </summary>
        /// <param name="services"> <see cref="IServiceCollection" />: the application's services container. </param>
        /// <param name="configuration"> <see cref="IConfiguration" />: the application's configuration. </param>
        /// <returns> The <see cref="IServiceCollection" /> with the various services added and configured. </returns>
        public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructureServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            // Register db context factory and configure options.
            string             connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString(ApplicationDbContext.ConnectionStringKey);
            MySqlServerVersion serverVersion    = new (ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
    
            services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion,
                                                                                           mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly("FLA.Infrastructure")));
    
            services.AddScoped<ApplicationDbContextInitializer>();
    
            // Pager.
            services.AddScoped<IPageHelper, PageHelper>();
    
            // Filters.
            services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserFilters, ApplicationUserFilterControls>();
    
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.AddAuthorization();
    
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Sign In settings.
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit           = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase       = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase       = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength         = 8;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars    = 1;
    
                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan  = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers      = true;
    
                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail        = true;
            });
    
            return services;
        }
    }
```

**ManageUsers.razor**

```
    @page "/ManageUsers"
    @page "/ManageUsers/{Page:int}"
    @inherits ManageUsersBase
    @attribute [ Authorize(Roles = "Administrator") ]
    
    <PageTitle>Manage Users</PageTitle>
    
    <h1>Manage Users</h1>
    
    <UserTableWrapper @ref="Wrapper"
                      FilterChanged="ReloadAsync"
                      DeleteRequested="id => Wrapper.DeleteRequestId = id">
    
        <div class="container-fluid users-table">
    
            <div class="row">
    
                <div class="col-2">
                    <NameToggle />
                    <span> &nbsp; @Filters.Loading</span>
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-8">
                    <TextFilter />
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                            @onclick="NewUser">➕ New User</button>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    
            <div class="row">
    
                <div class="col-6">
                    Page @Filters.PageHelper.Page of @Filters.PageHelper.PageCount: displaying @Filters.PageHelper.PageItems of @Filters.PageHelper.TotalItemCount users.
    
                    <a disabled="@(Filters.Loading || ! Filters.PageHelper.HasPrev)"
                       class="btn btn-primary @IsDisabled(Filters.PageHelper.HasPrev)"
                       href="@($"ManageUsers/{Filters.PageHelper.PrevPage}")">
                        Previous
                    </a>
    
                    <a disabled="@(Filters.Loading || ! Filters.PageHelper.HasNext)"
                       class="btn btn-primary @IsDisabled(Filters.PageHelper.HasNext)"
                       href="@($"ManageUsers/{Filters.PageHelper.NextPage}")">
                        Next
                    </a>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    
            <div class="row user-header">
    
                <div class="col-1">&nbsp;</div>
    
                <div class="col-2"
                     @onclick="@(async () => await ToggleAsync(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.Name))">
                    <SortIndicator Column="@(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.Name)" /> &nbsp; Name
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-4"
                     @onclick="@(async () => await ToggleAsync(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.Email))">
                    <SortIndicator Column="@(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.Email)" /> &nbsp; Email
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-2"
                     @onclick="@(async () => await ToggleAsync(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.Phone))">
                    <SortIndicator Column="@(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.Phone)" /> &nbsp; Phone
                </div>
    
                <div class="col-3"
                     @onclick="@(async () => await ToggleAsync(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.HighSchool))">
                    <SortIndicator Column="@(ApplicationUserFilterColumns.HighSchool)" /> &nbsp; High School
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            @if (Filters.Loading || Users is null)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 alert alert-info">
                        Loading...
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
    
            @if (Users is not null && Users.Count == 0)
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 alert alert-warning">
                        No users found.
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
    
            @if (Users is not null)
            {
                @foreach (ApplicationUser user in Users)
                {
                    <UserRow @key=user
                             CurrentUser="user"
                             DeleteUser="DeleteApplicationUserAsync" />
                }
            }
    
        </div>
    
    </UserTableWrapper>
```

**ManageUsersBase.cs**

```
    using FLA.Infrastructure.Persistence;
    
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    
    namespace FLA.WebUI.Models.UserManagement;
    
    /// <summary> Base for <see cref="ManageUsers" />. </summary>
    public class ManageUsersBase : ComponentBase
    {
        /// <summary> Keeps track of the last page loaded. </summary>
        private int _lastPage = -1;
    
        /// <summary> The <see cref="IApplicationUserFilters" /> injected through dependency injection. </summary>
        [ Inject ]
        protected IApplicationUserFilters Filters { get; set; } = default!;
    
        /// <summary> The <see cref="IDbContextFactory{ApplicationDbContext}" /> injected through dependency injection. </summary>
        [ Inject ]
        protected IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> DbContextFactory { get; set; } = default!;
    
        /// <summary> The <see cref="NavigationManager" /> injected through dependency injection. </summary>
        [ Inject ]
        protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; } = default!;
    
        /// <summary> The <see cref="ApplicationUserQueryAdapter" /> injected through dependency injection. </summary>
        [ Inject ]
        protected ApplicationUserQueryAdapter QueryAdapter { get; set; } = default!;
    
        /// <summary> The current page. </summary>
        [ Parameter ]
        public int Page { get => Filters.PageHelper.Page; set => Filters.PageHelper.Page = value; }
    
        /// <summary> A wrapper for user table related activity (like delete). </summary>
        protected UserTableWrapper Wrapper { get; set; } = new ();
    
        /// <summary> Current page of <see cref="ApplicationUser" />. </summary>
        protected ICollection<ApplicationUser>? Users { get; private set; }
    
        /// <summary> Helper method to set disabled on class for paging. </summary>
        /// <param name="condition"> <c> TRUE </c> when the element is active (and therefore should not be disabled). </param>
        /// <returns> The string literal <b> "disabled" </b> or an empty string. </returns>
        protected string IsDisabled(bool condition) => ! Filters.Loading && condition ? string.Empty : "disabled";
    
        /// <summary> Main logic when getting started. </summary>
        /// <param name="firstRender"> <c> TRUE </c> for first-time render. </param>
        protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
        {
            // Ensure we're on the same, er, right page.
            if (_lastPage < 1)
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/ManageUsers/1");
    
                return;
            }
    
            // Normalize the page values.
            if (Filters.PageHelper.PageCount > 0)
            {
                if (Page < 1)
                {
                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/ManageUsers/1");
    
                    return;
                }
    
                if (Page > Filters.PageHelper.PageCount)
                {
                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/ManageUsers/{Filters.PageHelper.PageCount}");
    
                    return;
                }
            }
    
            base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
        }
    
        /// <summary> Triggered for any paging update. </summary>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        {
            // Make sure the page really changed.
            if (Page != _lastPage)
            {
                _lastPage = Page;
                await ReloadAsync();
            }
    
            await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        ///     Used to toggle the table sort. Will either switch to "ascending" on a new column, or toggle between
        ///     "ascending" and "descending" on a column with the sort already set.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column"> The <see cref="ApplicationUserFilterColumns" /> to sort. </param>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        protected Task ToggleAsync(ApplicationUserFilterColumns column)
        {
            if (Filters.SortColumn == column)
            {
                Filters.SortAscending = ! Filters.SortAscending;
            }
            else
            {
                Filters.SortColumn = column;
            }
    
            return ReloadAsync();
        }
    
        /// <summary> Deletes a <see cref="ApplicationUser" />. </summary>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        protected async Task DeleteApplicationUserAsync()
        {
            await using ApplicationDbContext context = await DbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
            Filters.Loading = true;
    
            if (context.Users is not null)
            {
                ApplicationUser? user = await context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == Wrapper.DeleteRequestId);
    
                if (user is not null)
                {
                    context.Users.Remove(user);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
    
            Filters.Loading = false;
            await ReloadAsync();
        }
    
        /// <summary> Reloads the page on filters and paging controls. </summary>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        protected async Task ReloadAsync()
        {
            if (Filters.Loading || Page < 1)
            {
                return;
            }
    
            Filters.Loading = true;
    
            Wrapper.DeleteRequestId = Guid.Empty;
    
            Users = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    
            await using ApplicationDbContext context = await DbContextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();
            IQueryable<ApplicationUser>?     query   = context.Users?.AsQueryable();
    
            if (query is not null)
            {
                // Run the query to load the current page.
                Users = await QueryAdapter.FetchAsync(query);
            }
    
            // Now we're done.
            Filters.Loading = false;
        }
    
        /// <summary> Navigates to <see cref="AddUser" />. </summary>
        protected void NewUser()
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/UserNew");
        }
    }
```

**NameToggle.razor**

```
    @inherits NameToggleBase
    
    <button class="btn btn-primary"
            disabled="@Filters.Loading"
            @onclick="ToggleAsync">
        @Label - @Filters.Loading
    </button>
    &nbsp;
```

**NameToggleBase.cs**

```
    namespace FLA.WebUI.Models.UserManagement;
    
    /// <summary> Base mode for <see cref="NameToggle" />. </summary>
    public class NameToggleBase : ComponentBase
    {
        /// <summary> The <see cref="IApplicationUserFilters" /> injected through dependency injection. </summary>
        [ Inject ]
        protected IApplicationUserFilters Filters { get; set; } = default!;
    
        /// <summary> Button text based on current state. </summary>
        protected string Label => Filters.ShowFirstNameFirst ? "Display LAST, FIRST" : "Display FIRST LAST";
    
        /// <summary> Reference to the <see cref="UserTableWrapper" />. </summary>
        [ CascadingParameter ]
        public UserTableWrapper? Wrapper { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary> Toggle name preference. </summary>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        protected Task ToggleAsync()
        {
            Filters.ShowFirstNameFirst = ! Filters.ShowFirstNameFirst;
    
            return Wrapper is not null ? Wrapper.FilterChanged.InvokeAsync(this) : Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**UserRow.razor**

```
    @inherits UserRowBase
    
    @if (CurrentUser is not null)
    {
        <div class="row user-detail">
            <div class="col-1 text-right">
                <a title="Edit"
                   href="UserEdit/@CurrentUser.Id">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                </a>
    
                @if (CanDelete)
                {
                    <span @onclick="DeleteRequestAsync"
                          title="Delete"
                          class="clickable red">
                        ❌
                    </span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                }
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-2">
                <a href="@ViewLink"
                   alt="View User Details"
                   title="Details">
                    @Name
                </a>
            </div>
    
            @if (! DeleteConfirmation)
            {
                <div class="col-4">@CurrentUser.Email</div>
                <div class="col-2">@CurrentUser.PhoneNumber</div>
                <div class="col-3">@CurrentUser.HighSchool</div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="col-9">
                    <DeletePrompt Confirmation="ConfirmAsync" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
```

**UserRowBase.cs**

```
    namespace FLA.WebUI.Models.UserManagement;
    
    /// <summary> Base model for <see cref="UserRow" />. </summary>
    public class UserRowBase : ComponentBase
    {
        /// <summary> The <see cref="ApplicationUser" /> being rendered. </summary>
        private ApplicationUser _currentUser = new ();
    
        /// <summary> The <see cref="IApplicationUserFilters" /> injected through dependency injection. </summary>
        [ Inject ]
        public IApplicationUserFilters Filters { get; set; } = default!;
    
        /// <summary> The <see cref="ApplicationUser" /> being rendered. </summary>
        [ Parameter ]
        public ApplicationUser? CurrentUser
        {
            get => _currentUser;
    
            set
            {
                if (value is null || value.Equals(_currentUser))
                {
                    return;
                }
    
                _currentUser       = value;
                DeleteConfirmation = false;
            }
        }
    
        /// <summary> Event to raise when a user delete is requested. </summary>
        [ Parameter ]
        public EventCallback DeleteUser { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary> Overall wrapper of functionality. </summary>
        [ CascadingParameter ]
        public UserTableWrapper? TableWrapper { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary> Returns <c> TRUE </c> if conditions for delete are met. </summary>
        protected bool CanDelete => ! DeleteConfirmation && (TableWrapper?.DeleteRequestId == Guid.Empty || TableWrapper?.DeleteRequestId == CurrentUser?.Id);
    
        /// <summary> Navigate to the details page. </summary>
        protected string ViewLink => $"UserDetails/{CurrentUser?.Id}";
    
        /// <summary> Confirm the delete. </summary>
        protected bool DeleteConfirmation { get; set; }
    
        /// <summary> The user's correctly formatted name to be displayed. </summary>
        protected string Name => Filters.ShowFirstNameFirst ? $"{CurrentUser?.FirstName} {CurrentUser?.MiddleName} {CurrentUser?.LastName}"
                                     : $"{CurrentUser?.LastName}, {CurrentUser?.FirstName} {CurrentUser?.MiddleName}";
    
        /// <summary> Called based on confirmation. </summary>
        /// <param name="confirmed"> <c> TRUE </c> when confirmed. </param>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        protected async Task ConfirmAsync(bool confirmed)
        {
            if (confirmed)
            {
                await DeleteAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                DeleteConfirmation = false;
    
                if (TableWrapper is not null)
                {
                    await TableWrapper.DeleteRequested.InvokeAsync(Guid.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    
        /// <summary> Set delete to true. </summary>
        protected async Task DeleteRequestAsync()
        {
            if (TableWrapper?.DeleteRequestId == Guid.Empty && CurrentUser is not null)
            {
                DeleteConfirmation = true;
                await TableWrapper.DeleteRequested.InvokeAsync(CurrentUser.Id);
            }
        }
    
        /// <summary> Deletes the <see cref="ApplicationUser" />. </summary>
        /// <returns> A <see cref="Task" />. </returns>
        private Task DeleteAsync() => DeleteUser.InvokeAsync(this);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe when you navigate and back, They are in different scope, you can try to use AddSingleton  to register.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The code -behind pattern can be implemented either using partial classes or based classes which implement ```ComponentBase```. Both are equally acceptable.

Comment: @XinranShen The issue is that the state should only be preserved acrossed components per circuit. The Filters service is designed to dynamically render the UI based on whether the list of users is being generated or not. For example, if it is being generated, then the toggle button should be disabled because we don't want to modify a still-populating collection.

Comment: @XinranShen If I make the service a singleton, then any user accessing/reloading the page would cause the interactivity to lock-up for all users everywhere. I didn't include a snippet of the Filters service because my implementation is pretty much copy-paste from the linked demo. I just changed the class name/namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Revised Answer

Before I go into an explanation of what's going on, lets make the MS version do the same as yours.

Add the line indicated to the MS Code example.

```cs
public async Task<ICollection<Contact>> FetchAsync(IQueryable<Contact> query)
{
    query = FilterAndQuery(query);
    await CountAsync(query);
    // Add this line
    await Task.Delay(1);
    var collection = await FetchPageQuery(query)
        .ToListAsync();
    _controls.PageHelper.PageItems = collection.Count;
    return collection;
}
```

And when you start the application change the url to:

```
https://localhost:nnnn/7
```

And you'll get a disabled "Show First Name, Last Name" button.

Why?

Not simple.

The demo database in SQLite.  This line:

```cs
    await CountAsync(query);
```

looks like a yielding piece of async code.  It's a charade: it's just a block of Sync code in a async wrapper.  It runs to completion and never yields.  All the other DB stuff is the same.  Nothing yields so the UI doesn't update until `ReloadAsync` completes, and `IsLoading` is back to `false`.

In the code above we've added a yield.  The UI now gets built with `IsLoading` set to `false`.  As there are no component parameter changes between the first render, and the render that happens after `OnParametersSetAsync` completes, `NameToggle` doesn't re-render and remains disabled.

It works on the initial load because the page doesn't load anything, and navigates back to itself in `OnAfterRender`. `NameToggle` renders correctly first time round as `IsLoading` is never set to true.  On the reload, the page isn't re-rendered because it hasn't changed.  Only `OnParametersSetAsync` gets run.  `IsLoading` gets set to true and then back to false, but `NameToggle` never re-renders because none of it's parameters have changed.

You hit upon this because somewhere in your database code you are yielding, like that above.

The answer to the problem frankly is a re-design of the whole thing.  I'm a bit flaggerghasted by the design.  I need to think about how to bandaid it properly.  I'll update this answer when  I do.  Someone else might also make a suggestion.

### Quick Fix Update

The quick fix is to pass the loading state into `NameToggle` as a parameter.

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics
@inject IContactFilters Filters

<button class="btn btn-primary"
        disabled="@this.IsLoading"
        @onclick="ToggleAsync">
    @Label
</button>
&nbsp;
@RenderFragments.ShowRenderTime
@code {

//...
    [Parameter]public bool IsLoading { get; set; }
//...}
```

And then you do this:

```cs
<div class="col-4"><NameToggle IsLoading=this.Filters.Loading /></div>
```

Now when `GridWrapper` re-renders,  `SetParametersAsync` gets called on `NameToggle` if `filter.Loading` has changed, and it also re-renders.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try that debug technique. And while I suppose I understand what you mean that I would need an event or parameter, I don't understand why it works in the demo code. The demo code works exactly as expected and I cannot find any discrepancies between my code and theirs in how I've established the relationship between the components in question.

Comment: I will have a bit more of a dig into the MS code sample.

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you. You've helped me feel sane again! Would you elaborate your definition of "yield". I'm no expert with the TAP pattern, I just use it because it seems to be what everyone is doing. But I've also seen the "yield" keyword used in other contexts as well.

Comment: NP.  See my revised answer for the quick fix.  A few comments. Treat this as a demo.  It's definitely not the way I would put something like this together.  2. It breaks a few rules/recommendations that have evolved. 3. Read up and get to understand intimately the component lifecycle.  Understanding components properly will save you a lot of time.

Comment: `Yielding` is very difficult to describe succinctly.   In your example a method makes a call  to the database to do something.  The code after the call is called the continuation.  Yielding means instead of waiting for the database to reply, the continuation is pushed down the thread queue.   This means other code stacked on the queue can be run - such as a re-render event on a component - before the database returns the result and the continuation can complete.  Search `Blazor Async` for some relevant articles.

Comment: I'm afraid most search results for `Blazor Async` will not be about UI updating. It's surprising how often Delay(1) is the solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - there's one of mine on the subject out there.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't float to the top directly. And btw, Blazor Server has a Sync context. In Wasm it is `null`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman.  Just re-read it and yes, a small edit required.  I don't reference it directly as the local police might get antsy!

Comment: Let me qualify my search statement.  Use a search engine like DuckDuckGo or Bing, not an advertising portal.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I've gone ahead and marked this as the answer. Thank you for taking the time to review the demo and provide such a thorough and helpful answer. I am eternally grateful.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I believe I now understand what you're saying. In the render process of a component, the lifecycle process continues after the first await. This makes sense as it allows the component to render without having to wait for backend tasks to complete (kinda the whole point of Blazor) and it doesn't cause multiple re-renders. Let me know if I'm thinking along the same lines as you.

Comment: For reference, I came to this understanding after reading the section "Awaiting within Async lifecycle methods" of https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/.